# Magento 2 cron reindex causes Page Cache to be invalidated

Tags: cron, magento2.4.1

I am running the following to reindex my products and categories on a schedule

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -c /opt/plesk/php/7.4/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product catalog_product_category
```

This works fine except every time it runs it tells me that the Page Cache is invalidated

Answer (score 0):

If you set your indexers to be 'updated on schedule', rather than 'on save', the above mentioned behavior wouldn't be so visible, it would take place gradually.

And also, depending on what your operations on the products/ categories are, the behavior you mentioned is pretty logical, isn't it? You are updating data on the entities, then reindex in order to propagate the correct updated data, which causes FPC to be invalidated and require a refresh.

Comment: I have Category Products and Product Categories set to updated on schedule, the issue also happens when there have been no product/category changes

Comment: i think this has to do with the fact that you are fully reindexing the data. basically the index tables are emptied out and data is reinserted, so it's normal to have the FPC invalidated. why are you reindexing these indexes by 'hand' actually? if you have them on 'update on schedule' and you have the crons set up right, there shouldn't be any need of doing this as you mentioned in your post.

Comment: I am running the ```/opt/plesk/php/7.4/bin/php -c /opt/plesk/php/7.4/etc/php.ini /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/httpdocs/bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product catalog_product_category
```
because I have an issue with products not showing in categories at random times, manually reindexing fixes the issue but  it will happen again after a random time period. I know doing it this way isn't really a fix but it gives me more time to investigate the original issue further

Comment: yeah, ok, but why? :)

Comment: Sorry I hit the enter key before finishing typing!

Comment: well, unless you fix the actual issue, this workaround will have to 'pay the consequences', namely have FPC invalidated everytime.. sorry mate!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not an answer but a question. I've got the same issue, products randomly disappear from categories. Have you manageto to find what's causing it?